# Exercise 5.14(d), chapter I in Hartshorne

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $f$ be an irreducible polynomial in $k[x,y]$ such that $P=(0,0)$ is a double point of $Y=Z(f)$, that is, $f=f_2+f_3+\cdots$, where $f_i$'s are homogeneous term of degree $i$, $f_2\neq0$, then we want to show that $k[[x,y]]/(f)\cong k[[x,y]]/(y^2-x^r)$ for some $r\geq 2$. (here char $k\neq2$).

If $f_2$ has two different linear factor, by a linear transform, then $k[[x,y]]/(f)\cong k[[x,y]]]/(xy)$. By a linear transform again, we have  $k[[x,y]]]/(xy)\cong k[[x,y]]/(y^2-x^2)$. Hence $k[[x,y]]]/(f)\cong k[[x,y]]/(y^2-x^2)$.

If $f_2$ has only one linear factor, by a linear transform, W.L.O.G., we can assume that $f_2=y^2$. Since $f$ is irreducible in $k[x,y]$, then there exists some $r\geq3$ such that $x^r$ appears in $f_r$, here we can assume that $r$ is the smallest such number. Now I want to find some automatism $\phi$ of $k[[x,y]]$ such that $\phi(y^2-x^r)=f$. But I got stuck.

Comment: Do you know Weierstrass preparation theorem?

Comment: @ Mohan I saw the Weierstrass preparation theorem for $\mathbb{C}$ in some answer sets, is it also true for general characteristic?

Comment: Yes, and you can look up a proof in Lang's algebra.

Answer (score 4):

Let's develop the discussion from the comments. Remember, we're trying to finish the solution in the case when $f_2=y^2$.

> **Weierstrass Preperation theorem** (Bourbaki's Commutative Algebra, VII.3.8 prop 6): Let $A$ be a complete local ring. If $f=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nt^n \in A[[t]]$ so that not all $a_i$ are in the maximal ideal of $A$, there is a unique unit $u\in A[[t]]$ and a unique polynomial $F$ of the form $F=t^s+b_{s-1}t^{s-1}+\cdots+b_0$ with $b_i\in\mathfrak{m}$ so that $f=uF$.

We apply this with $A=k[[x]]$ and $y$ in the role of $t$. The conclusion of the theorem gives us that $f=u \cdot(y^2+y\cdot v(x)+ w(x))$. Next, as $\operatorname{char} k\neq 2$, we may substitute $y=y-\frac{1}{2}v(x)$, which takes $y^2+y\cdot v(x)+w(x)$ to $y^2-w'(x)$. By the assumption that $P$ is a double point, $w'(x)$ has valuation at least two. As $k$ is algebraically closed, we may scale $x$ so that $w'(x)=x^n(1+U(x))$ where $U(x)$ has no constant term. Then we may then use the fact that $\sqrt{1+x}=\sum_{i=0}^\infty \binom{1/2}{i}x^i$ is defined for any field of characteristic not two in order to construct the automorphism $y\mapsto y\cdot\sqrt{1+U(x)}$ and see that $k[[x,y]]/(y^2-w'(x))\cong k[[x,y]]/(y^2-x^n)$ for $n>2$. (Thanks to kindasorta for pointing out the step involving $\sqrt{1+x}$.) By the uniqueness of $u$ and $F$ from the theorem, the uniqueness of the substituiont $y=y-\frac12v(x)$, and the fact that all further transformations don't change the order of the power series in $x$, we see that $n$ is uniquely determined.

Comment: Thank you! I have been trying to use Weierstrass preparation on $x^r$ all along, while it was supposed to be used on $y^2$... Sometimes, things are as simple as that. Thank you for pointing out the degenerate case of $n = \mathrm{char}(k)$! This was missing from the book.

Comment: Can you explain why $k[[x,y]]/(g)$ is not isomorphic to other $k[[x,y]]/(y^2-x^{r})$ where $r \neq p$?

Comment: @LaiZehua the minimal exponent of $x$ occurring in $y^2-w'(x)$ is uniquely determined from the input data of $f$, because Weierstrass preparation returns a unique result and the transformation $y\mapsto y-\frac12 v(x)$ is uniquely determined from this data. Any automorphism of $k[[x,y]]$ sending $y^2-w'(x)$ to $y^2-w''(x)$ must preserve the lowest power of $x$ appearing in $w''$: such an automorphism is given by $x\mapsto a_1x+a_2x^2+\cdots$. This means that $r=p$, but we showed that can't be the case above.

Comment: Maybe I missed something here. I think there is still a possibiliy that an automorphism maps $y^2−w′(x)$ to some general $f(x, y)$ and $f(x, y)$ is differed from $y^2−w'′(x)$ by a unit.

Comment: @LaiZehua I've adjusted the argument at the end. Let me know how it reads to you.

Comment: Thanks! This makes perfect sense.

Comment: It is also possible to write $w'(x) = x^n\cdot u(x)$, where $u(x) = 1 + x\cdot U(x)$ is a unit, and make the change of variables $x\mapsto x$ and $y\mapsto \sqrt{u(x)}y$, which always exists if the characteristic of $k$ is different from 2.

Comment: @kindasorta that's a good suggestion - it's been a bit since I touched this post, and I'm wondering whether you think the claim about $y^2-x^p-x^{p+1}$ not being able to be transformed in to $y^2-x^p$ survives or not. Totally happy to dive back in and amend this answer, but it's just been a while and it's not so fresh in my mind.

Comment: It necessarily doesn't, evidently. I am also curious to see what fails.

Comment: @kindasorta I've edited the post to include the material you've pointed out and thanked you for your contribution. The issue with the previous work was that I had made a small but important error in my calculations with the power series which was glossed over in the written proof here. Thanks again for the correction.